# Previous sponsors of Premier League

Tags: football, english-premier-league

From the 2016/17 season onwards, the English Premier League [won't have a title sponsor](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sport/football/article-3111413/Premier-League-without-title-sponsor-2016-17-season-bid-mirror-major-American-sports-clean-branding-strategy.html) (last one being Barclays) and will simply be known as the Premier League.

Barclays has been the title sponsor since 2004.

Who were the sponsors before that (and what period of time they had sponsorship for), or was Barclays the first?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Barclays was the second sponsor and the first sponsor was [Carling](https://www.carling.com/) from the 1993/94 season (there was no sponsor for the first season) to 2001/02 season when the titile sponsor changed from Carling to Barclays.

The linked [EPL history on premierleague.com](https://www.premierleague.com/history) states

> Apart from the opening campaign in 1992/93, every season of the
>   Premier League has had a title sponsor. From the 1993/94 season,
>   England’s top flight was known as the FA Carling Premiership, before
>   the sponsorship changed in 2001 to Barclaycard until 2004.
>
> The title of the competition then changed to the FA Barclays
>   Premiership, with this being amended to Barclays Premier League ahead
>   of the 2007/08 campaign.
>
> Season 2015/16 marked the final campaign of a title sponsor
>   arrangement, with the competition name becoming Premier League from
>   2016/17.

For more information, you can read [Carling on premierleague.com](https://www.premierleague.com/partners/carling).